# ¿Cómo imprimir los datos actuales de la base de datos en mi DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un `GridView`el cual imprime en unos `Labels`, la información que llamo desde la Base de datos. Pero tambien estoy tratando de imprimir los datos que ya se registraron en la base de datos en un `DropDownList` que se encuentra en un `GridView`.
Pero al momento de dar clic en `Update` se cambian todos los datos por los que mando a llamar cuando voy a crear un registro.

Quiero saber como mantener estatico el valor que tiene el `label` al momento de dar `Update`

En el evento `Page_Load`el codigo que uso es el siguiente

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*********************************************************************************/
            /******************************FILL THE GRIDVIEW**********************************/
            /*********************************************************************************/

            DataTable advt = ARSBTable.areaconnect();
            GridView1.DataSource = advt;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            /*********************************************************************************/

            /*********************************************************************************/
            /************************INSERT DATA TO THE DROPDOWN LIST*************************/
            /*********************************************************************************/

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable rdvt = RESBTable.regconnect();

                this.Dpo_tool.DataSource = rdvt;

                this.Dpo_tool.DataTextField = "tool_id";
                this.Dpo_tool.DataSource = rdvt;
                this.Dpo_tool.DataBind();
                this.Dpo_tool.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Herramienta", String.Empty));

                this.Dpo_torque.DataSource = rdvt;

                this.Dpo_torque.DataTextField = "torque_max";
                this.Dpo_torque.DataSource = rdvt;
                this.Dpo_torque.DataBind();
                this.Dpo_torque.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Torque", String.Empty));

                /*********************************************************************************/
                /************************INSERT NAME TO THE DROPDOWN LIST*************************/
                /*********************************************************************************/
                this.Dpo_buckets.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Buckets", String.Empty));
                this.Dpo_pool.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Pool", String.Empty));
                this.Dpo_team.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Team", String.Empty));
                this.Dpo_station.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Station", String.Empty));
                this.Dpo_operation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Operation", String.Empty));
                /*********************************************************************************/


                /*********************************************************************************/
                /************************INSERT DATA TO THE DROPDOWN LIST*************************/
                /*********************************************************************************/

                DataTable udvt = USBTable.connect();

                this.Dpo_tl.DataSource = udvt;

                this.Dpo_tl.DataTextField = "who";
                this.Dpo_tl.DataSource = udvt;
                this.Dpo_tl.DataBind();
                this.Dpo_tl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Team Leader", String.Empty));
            }
        }
```

un ejemplo seria este:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tool">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="gv_tool" runat="server">
               </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tool_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
               <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

y el codigo que uso para llenar los `DropDownList` al momento de dar `Update` es el siguiente

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList ddTool = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("gv_tool");
                    DataTable rdvt = RESBTable.regconnect();

                    ddTool.DataTextField = "tool_id";
                    ddTool.DataSource = rdvt;
                    ddTool.DataBind();

                    DropDownList ddTorque = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("gv_torque");

                    ddTorque.DataTextField = "torque_max";
                    ddTorque.DataSource = rdvt;
                    ddTorque.DataBind();

                    DropDownList ddteam = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("gv_tl");
                    DataTable udvt = USBTable.connect();

                    ddteam.DataTextField = "who";
                    ddteam.DataSource = udvt;
                    ddteam.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Valor impreso desde la base de datos]

Quisiera que el valor que esta en el `Label`se quede en el `DropDownList`

[image: Al momento de dar clic en Update]

Answer (score 0):

Escribe el código en una función y llamalo en el evento `pageload`
(Dado que no has proporcionado código he puesto uno de ejemplo)

Tienes que poner `DataTextField` y `DatavalueField`

```
objc.ClientName = Convert.ToString(Session["ClientName"]);
            DataSet ClientN = obj.GetClientList();
            DataView Projview = new DataView();
            Projview.Table = ClientN.Tables[0];
            DrpClientName.DataSource = Projview;
            DrpClientName.DataTextField="Description";
            DrpClientName.DataValueField="ID";
            DrpClientName.DataBind();
```

Comment: Acabo de colocar el codigo que uso para el `Page_Load`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos entonces, en vez de llamar directamente, te recomiendo usar objetos como en el ejemplo

Comment: Despues de agregar eso tengo que ponerle algo al `DropDownList`?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos claro, en vez de llamar a los datos, en el `DropDownList` llamas a los objetos como te he indicado, así que con cambiar eso debería valer, hazmelo saber :)

Comment: oooh ya entiendo! lo ponder a prueba, cualquier cosa yo te informo